# Generate pagination numbers with current item in the middle with javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Hello I try to generate pagination numbers from given variables:

- **itemsPerPage** : How many elements to display per page
- **nbDisplayPage**: How many pages display in pagination
- **nbItems** : How many items is contain in the list
- **current**: Current Page

#### What is the expected output?

function signature:  `getPaginationArray(nbItems, current, itemsPerPage=10, nbDisplayPage=3)`

- `getPaginationArray(40, 4)` -> `[2, 3, 4]`
- `getPaginationArray(40, 1)` -> `[1, 2, 3]`
- `getPaginationArray(200, 5)` -> `[4, 5, 6]`
- `getPaginationArray(10, 1)` -> `[1]`
- `getPaginationArray(11, 2)` -> `[1, 2]`
- `getPaginationArray(40, 5)` -> `Error`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I already write this code, but it looks a bit dirty, how to make it cleaner?

```js
  function getPaginationArray(nbItems, current, itemsPerPage=10, nbDisplayPage=3){
    const nbPages = Math.ceil(nbItems / itemsPerPage);
    const elements = []
    let i = 0
    let biggerElement = 0
 if(current > nbPages){
     throw new Error("Current can not be bigger than nbPages")
    }
    
    elements.push(current)
 // get element after
    const after = parseInt(nbDisplayPage / 2)
    for (i = 1; i <= after; i++) {
      if (current + i > nbPages) {
        break
      }
      elements.push(current + i)
    }
    biggerElement = i
  
    // get element before
    let rest = nbDisplayPage - elements.length
    for (i = 1; i <= rest; i++) {
      if (current - i === 0) {
        break
      }
      elements.push(current - i)
    }

    // add rest after
    rest = nbDisplayPage - elements.length
    if (rest) {
      for (i = biggerElement; i < rest + biggerElement; i++) {
        if (current + i > nbPages) {
          break
        }
        elements.push(current + i)
      }
    }

    elements.sort((a, b) => a - b)
    return elements
  }


console.log('expected output: [1,2,3]', getPaginationArray(40, 1))
console.log('expected output: [2,3,4]', getPaginationArray(40, 4))
console.log('expected output: [4,5,6]', getPaginationArray(200, 5))
console.log('expected output: [1]', getPaginationArray(10, 1))
console.log('expected output: [1,2]', getPaginationArray(11, 1))
console.log('expected output: [1,2]', getPaginationArray(11, 2))
console.log('expected output: Error', getPaginationArray(40, 5))
```